# numpy.int64 to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Leo un fichero en pandas y recojo el valor de una celda de la hoja EXCEL

digamos

```
prov = lectura.iat[1,7]
```

me dice que prov es del tipo `numpy.int64` con `print(type(prov))`

entonces como que quiero usar esta variable sumandola a una cadena de texto.

hago

```
prov_str=str(prov)
```

y no me deja, el error es:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

lo he hecho muchas veces y siempre me funcionó. uso Python 3.6)

Comment: a mi me parece que has usado `str` y la has sobreescrito, algo como `str = foo_value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En una parte anterior del código has redefinido `str` con lo cual al querer "castear" ya está redefinido.

Answer (score 0):

nada! falsa alarma, la solución reiniciar la consola,... pero a veces me hace dudar de mi propia existencia el dichoso python. Gracias en cualquier caso. Un saludo